# Add left border to image in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

Is it possible to assign the left border to an image in like my attached image in which it have left strip border?

We need to assign the image to border or we can do it with border image ?
Can anyone please Help?

Thanks in advance.

Here is the sample image:

[image]

Result after apply the code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by:

**Method 1** - where you don't want to overlap that small part of the image:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Method 2** - where you want to overlap the image with the border:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/my_image" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="8dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF0000" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yes great it works for me.
One question will it work when my image height is increase?

Comment: Yes it will. It all depends on the height of the parent. You could use a fixed size for that. I would not recommend having each item's height based on the image's height. That would make your app look bad. Another key component is the scaleType property of the ImageView.

Comment: i just apply your code and paste the result in my question, 
I think we are close can you please help little bit more to fix this ?

Comment: I think your image has a white border on top and bottom that's why it seems that it does not scale up properly. If you'd like to, you can play around with the scaleType property. This way you'll learn how that behaves too :)

Comment: Actually it works with Scaltype property, You answer useful too.

Answer (score 2):

try this, I have done it.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/tcit" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#336699" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In your layout file, if you need it in landscape, just do it the same orientation which you need, and I have attached a snapshot for this, kindly have a look to it.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic it works perfect for me. Thank you very much.
Just change Relativelayout to Linearlayout.

Comment: Linearlayout will take one view after that take another view, where as relative layout overlay your so many views..anyways njoy, if you like the answer, please accept it.:)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, i am new with android so :)

Comment: your wlcm any time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by creating one layout over another, setting the colors required in your background layout and adding a left margin to the upper layout.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it with Some code ?
Or can i use the image as a border?

Comment: I haven't got a PC with me, I can't now

Comment: ok But no problem but please let me know if you can do it later.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just set a background color (or even another image) to the ImageView and give it a left padding:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_res" />
```